# How do you read this ternary condition in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, multiline, ternary-operator

I came across a ternary in some code and I am having trouble understanding the conditional:

```
str.split(/',\s*'/).map do |match|
  match[0] == ?, ?
    match : "some string"
end.join
```

I do understand that I am splitting a string at certain points and converting the total result to an array, and dealing with each element of the array in turn. Beyond that I have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A (slightly) less confusing way to write this is:

```
str.split(/',\s*'/).map do |match|
  if match[0] == ?,
    match
  else
    "some string"
  end
end.join
```

I think multiline ternary statements are horrible, especially since `if` blocks can return in Ruby.

Probably the most confusing thing here is the `?,` which is a character literal. In Ruby 1.8 this means the ASCII value of the character (in this case `44`), in Ruby 1.9 this is just a string (in this case `","`).

The reason for using a character literal instead of just `","` is that the return value of calling `[]` on a string changed in Ruby 1.9. [In 1.8 it returned the ASCII value of the character at that position](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-5B-5D), [in 1.9 it returns a single-character string](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D). Using `?,` here avoids having to worry about the differences in `String#[]` between Ruby 1.8 & 1.9.

Ultimately the conditional is just checking if the first character in `match` is `,`, and if so it keeps the value the same, else it sets it to `"some string"`.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMarshall, it would have helped if it was `match == ( ?, ) ? match : "some string"` ? Or would that mean something else?

Comment: @IsmailTabtabai That would be the same. Whenever I do ternary statements I usually wrap the whole conditional statement in parenthesis to make it clear where it is, but that's just style. Character literals are probably one of the lesser-known syntactic structures of Ruby, and can be very confusing when you don't know what it is (especially when paired with other `?`s).

Comment: It means the same thing. So would match[0] == ?, ? match : "some string"